# I'm trying to ensure movements of features in 2D array are correct, but I cannot seem to find the logic error preventing this from working correctly

Tags: c++

I have a record structure type SRI with an initialized 2D array (called SimArr) all set to constant integer Empty (which is = 0). Then I created a random number-generating function to place a certain amount of 1s, 2s, 3s and 4s inside the array. The quantities of these numbers as well as size of the array are specified in cmd arguments, which I set to the size of 10 rows and 10 columns. There are four 1s, five 2s, two 3s and one 4. That worked just fine, but now I'm randomly trying to move each 1, 2, 3, and 4 up, down, left, right, or to its closest diagonals. These numbers can't touch each other or exit the bounds of the array. I tested this code, and the movements were looked at. The number 4 started at (rows, columns) of (8,3) then moved to (9,2), then (8,2), then (7,1) which is what I wanted, but then the location jumped randomly to (10,0), which is definitely not what I am looking for. How do I fix this? Here are some relevant snippets of code:

```
`void  GenRanPlace(SRI Sim, int numperson, int TypePerson, int rows, int cols)
   {
        for(int x = 0;  x < numperson; x++)
      {
         int row = Random(0, rows - 1);
         int col = Random(0, cols - 1);
         
         while(Sim.SimArr[row][col] != Empty)
         {
          row = Random(0, rows - 1) ;
          col = Random(0, cols - 1);
         }
         
         Sim.SimArr[row][col] = TypePerson;
       
      }
   }`
  
   
   
  bool CheckValid(SRI Sim, int rows, int cols, int destrow, int destcol, int row, int col)
  {
      if(destrow >= 0 && destrow < rows  && destcol >= 0 && destcol <cols)
      {
          
             if((abs(row - destrow) <= 1) && (abs(col - destcol) <= 1))
             {
                if(Sim.SimArr[destrow][destcol] == Empty)
                {
                    return true;
                }
             }
          
    
      }
             return false;  
  }

 
    void MovePeople(SRI & Sim, int rows, int cols)
    
    {
        
       for(int y = 0; y < rows; y++) 
       {
           for(int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
           {
               int DestinationRow = y;
               int DestinationCol = x;
               
               int value = Random(0,7);
               
               switch(value)
               {
               case 0: //move up 
               DestinationRow--;
               break;
               
               case 1: //move down
               DestinationRow++;
               break;
               
               case 2: //move left
               DestinationCol--;
               break;
               
               case 3:
               DestinationCol++;
               break;
               
               case 4: 
                DestinationRow--;
                DestinationCol--;
                 break;

                case 5:  // move up-right
                    DestinationRow--;
                    DestinationCol++;
                    break;

                case 6:  // move down-left
                    DestinationRow++;
                    DestinationCol--;
                    break;

                case 7:  // move down-right
                    DestinationRow++;
                    DestinationCol++;
                    break;
               
               }
               
               if(CheckValid(Sim, rows, cols, DestinationRow, DestinationCol, y, x))
               {
                   Sim.SimArr[DestinationRow][DestinationCol] =  Sim.SimArr[y][x];
                   Sim.SimArr[y][x] = Empty;
        
               }
               
               
               
           }
       }
        
        
        
        
        
    }
        
//inside main function:

  
    do
    {
        
        
    PrintGame(Rows, Cols, Sim);
    cin >> chEntry;
    
    switch(chEntry)
    {
        case 'A':
        case 'a': 
        MovePeople(Sim, Rows, Cols);
        break;
        
        case 'Q':
        case 'q':
        blnRun = false;
        break;
    
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    }while(blnRun);
    
    
    
    
    

    
    
    

`
```

//I tried to look for errors in the MovePeople and CheckValid function, but I just cannot seem to locate the bug. Yes, I'm new to programming. Your help would be very much appreciated. <3

Comment: How are you calling these two functions ? with what parameters ? Your problem seems to need debugging, so please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is `SRI`? In the code, objects of that type are passed *by value* in some functions and the *local* copies are modified.